# How to iterate a function 8 times about a given interval of x in a Discrete Dynamical System

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, transfinite-recursion, chaos-theory

This is Dynamical Systems, specifically a discrete system. We are using L and R as in Left and Right such as:

L=[0,0.5]

R=(0.5,1]

and LL=[0,0.25]

LR=(0.25,0.5] and so on like that. We keep splitting the interval in halves, where L represents left and R represents right.

Also this is a Logistic Map between [0,1] only.

Q:You have f(x)=4x(1−x) and xo element of LLRRRRLRRLR;

b) Is f^{8}(x_o) greater than (>), equal to (=) or less than (<) 1/2?

Here f^{8}(x_o) means f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x_o)))))))).

They want to know if that is greater than, equal to or less than one half.

A: I got a & c, which I omitted.

I'm stuck for b), I have no way to know how to compute the 8th iteration of the function f at x_o. Does it have something to do with LLRRRRLRRLR?

Thanks,

Comment: it has to do with the image of the extremes of that interval - which are dyadic fractions you can perfectly calculate (they have denominator $2^11$), and iterate the logistic function on.

Comment: I was able to find the interval of x_o using dyadic fractions, but what I don't get is how am I supposed to iterate the function f(x)=4x(1-x) 8 times, it becomes a huge problem. Is there a trick or a way to shorten the process? This assignment is all paper and pencil.

Comment: Are you then sure that the map is not the linear one? ($f(x) = 2x$ for $x<0.5$ and $f(x) = 2(1-x)$ for $x≥0.5$) This map sends "named" intervals into other named intervals by shift and swap, basically it acts deleting the first letter, and then if it was a R swapping every letter with its opposite.

Comment: Throwing something like `N[Nest[4*#*(1-#) &, 493/2048, 8 ]]` to wolfram alpha allow you to compute the value of your function numerically.